# Как в динамическом списке поменять местами 2 элемента?

Tags: pascal, список, списки, динамические-массивы

Хочу понять, как обменивать элементы в двусвязном списке, перекидывая ссылки. Что нужно сделать в процедуре swap, например для того чтобы поменять первый и последний элементы

```
const n = 10; 

type
  PList = ^TList;
  TList = record
    info: integer;
    pred, next: PList;
  end;

procedure makeList(var head, tail: plist);//создание списка
var
  p: Plist;
  i: integer;   
begin//makeList
  new(head);
  new(tail);
  head^.next := tail;
  tail^.pred := head;//сторожа
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    new(p);
    p^.info := random(10)-5;
    p^.next := tail;
    p^.pred := tail^.pred;
    p^.pred^.next := p;
    tail^.pred := p;
  end;
end;//makeList

procedure swap(head, tail: plist);
var
  p: Plist;  
begin 
  new(p);
  p:=head^.next;
  head^.next:=tail^.pred;
  tail^.pred:=p;
end;

procedure outList(head, tail: plist);//вывод списка
var
  p: plist; 
begin//outLIst
  p := head^.next;
  while p <> tail do
  begin
    write(p^.info:4);
    p := p^.next;
  end;
end;//outList


var
  head, tail: PList;
begin
  makeList(head, tail);
  writeln('Before:');
  outlist(head,tail);
  swap(head, tail);
  writeln();
  writeln('After:');
  outList(head, tail);
  writeln();
end;
```

Comment: Если вам нужно поменять местами два произвольных элемента, я бы посоветовал свести это к процедурам «убрать элемент из списка» и «добавить элемент в список».

Comment: Вообще, задача стоит такая: Дан список из n целых чисел.Переместить в начало все отрицательные элементы списка в начало, а положительные в конец.

Comment: А почему бы просто не пройтись по списку, удалить все положительные элементы и добавить их в новый список, а потом пристыковать новый список в хвост старому?

Answer (score 1):

Нет смысла менять местами сами элементы. достаточно поменять местами info:

```
procedure swap(head, tail: plist);
var 
    temp: integer
begin 
    temp := head^.info;    
    head^.info := head^.tail;
    tail^.info := temp;        
end;
```

результат будет точно таким же, как если бы вы поменяли местами сами элементы списка.

Comment: В том то и сложность, что мне надо поменять ссылки, а не info

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon если вы поменяете местами ссылки, потом корректно подправите ссылки на соедние элементы, потом подправите ссылку на начало и на конец списка - то вы получите **точно такую же** картину, как просто при смене info.

Comment: @PashaPash: Смысл может быть, если данные реально тяжёлые, и перемещение их дороже, чем перемещение ссылок.

Comment: @VladD у топикастера вполне конкретные данные - int. и даже задача поставлена как "переместить отрицательные/положительные элементы". в его случае проще два инта переставить, чем поменять 6 ссылок (причем не запутаться при изменении).

Comment: @PashaPash: Это да, но учебные задания обычно лишь моделируют реальные. Требование перемещать ссылки, а не данные, вполне может быть обоснованным.

Comment: @VladD в реальной ситуации я бы не советовал хранить в списке толстый value type.

Comment: @PashaPash: Хм, а где хранить? И почему? Допустим, мы организовываем очередь данных на обработку. Упаковать в reference type — лишний уровень косвенности, возможно, ненужный.

Comment: Хотя вопрос о реальном юзкейсе, да, интересный.

Comment: @VladD можно допустить все что угодно. например что надо работать со списком int. и тогда перестановка нод целиком - лишняя работа, возможно, ненужная. Или там будет уже reference type, и тогда перестановка нод целиком тоже не нужна. Я сомневаюсь что реальные задачи со списками кто-то решает на паскале в наше время :(